# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields' (ODOO 12)

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

i inherited from the product.template to add some customer fields , i'm trying to make those fields appear in the product page on the website and it's not working , i had this error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields' Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo
> 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\qweb.py", line 347, in _compiled_fn
> return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)   File "", line 1, in template_website_sale_product_price_297
> File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo
> 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_qweb.py", line 368, in _get_field
> field = record._fields[field_name] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields'
>
> Error to render compiling AST AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no
> attribute '_fields' Template: website_sale.product_price Path:
> /templates/t/span Node:

this is my code in the main of controllers :

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request
from odoo.addons.website_sale.controllers.main import WebsiteSale


class WebsiteSaleInherit(WebsiteSale):
    @http.route(['/shop/product/<model("product.template"):product>'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
    def product(self, product, category='', search='', **kwargs):
        res = super(WebsiteSaleInherit, self).product(product, category='', search='', **kwargs)
        return res
```

this the xml code :

```
<odoo>
<template id="website_inherit" inherit_id="website_sale.product_price" customize_show="True" name="property details">
      <xpath expr="//div[@class='product_price mt16']" position="after">
          <p> Informations :</p>
          <span t-field="Catimmo.surface"/>
      </xpath>
</template>
        </odoo>
```

this the python file :

```
import logging
from odoo import models, fields, api, _

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Catimmo(models.Model):
    #_name = "catimmo"
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    surface = fields.Float(string='Surface')
    prop = fields.Char(string="Proprietaire")
    ref = fields.Char(string="Reference")
    immo_cat = fields.Selection(string='Categorie', selection=
    [('appartement', 'Appartement'), ('maison', 'Maison'), ('terrain', 'Terrain'), ('local', 'Local commercial'),
     ('bureau', 'Bureau'), ('garage_parking', 'Garage/Parking')], required=True)
    immo_titre = fields.Char('Titre de l'"annonce", required=True)
    immo_date = fields.Datetime('Date de publication')
    img_one = fields.Binary('Image Num 1 ')
    img_two = fields.Binary('Image Num 2 ')
    nbre_ch = fields.Integer(string="Nombre des chambres", required=True)
    pr = fields.Float(string="Prix du bien immobilier")
    type_immob = fields.Selection(selection=
                                  [('appartement', 'Appartement'), ('maison', 'Maison'), ('terrain', 'Terrain'),
                                   ('local', 'Local commercial'),
                                   ('bureau', 'Bureau'), ('garage_parking', 'Garage/Parking')])
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE =)

Comment: In `product()`, you are always passing an empty string to the parent's `category` and `search` parameters, rather than passing along the values supplied by the caller. Surely this is part of the problem...

Comment: i still have the same problem        @kindall class WebsiteSaleInherit(WebsiteSale):
    @http.route(['/shop/product/<model("product.template"):product>'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
    def product(self, product, category='', search='', **kwargs):
        res = super(WebsiteSaleInherit, self).product(product, category, search)
        return res

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `t-field` directive can only be used when performing field access (`a.b`) on a **"smart"** record (the result of the `browse` method).

The error message tells us that `Catimmo` is of `NoneType` (maybe used before declaration)

In your template, when you use:

```
<span t-field="Catimmo.surface"/>
```

Odoo will try to get the `surface` field from `Catimmo` record, make sure `Catimmo` is defined and it is a smart record.

The `product` record is available and can be used inside `website_sale.product_price`.

Set the surface of your product and try to use `product` instead of `Catimmo` variable:

```
<span t-field="product.surface"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer help you.

Comment: yes it helped thank you , but it's not working with boolean fields =(

Comment: Please add more details on what you expect and why you think it is not working?